Raspberry Pi 5 GPIOZERO
I just started learning how to use the raspberry pi. One of the first issues I encountered with the raspberry pi was that the most common library (the one that all tutorials use) RPi.GPIO does not work with the raspberry pi 5 due to hardware changes. This means I have to use a library that supports the new hardware like the gpiod or GPIOZERO. I was told to use GPIOZERO as it is more begginer friendly and has more features like pwm and built in pull up resistors.
Upon trying to turn on a led with the GPIOZERO library, I encountered an issue where my code wasn’t making the gpio pin output any voltage (I tested this with a multimeter). Here is my python code:
from gpiozero import LED
led = LED(17)
led.on()

When I try to use the gpiod library it works perfectly fine:
Here is the code:
import gpiod
LED_PIN = 17
chip = gpiod.Chip('gpiochip4')
led_line = chip.get_line(LED_PIN)
led_line.request(consumer="LED", type=gpiod.LINE_REQ_DIR_OUT)
led_line.set_value(1)

The reason why I don't want to use the gpiod library in the long term is that I'm pretty sure it doesn't support internal pull up resistors or pwm.
I wonder if it is an issue with the new chip system on the raspberry pi 5. Does anyone know how I can fix this?
I tried switching around the gpio pin from 17 to 11, nothing changed, I've tried researching if it might be something to do with the new chip system, but I found that this exact code and wiring worked for other Pi 5 users.

GPIO 2 is part of an I2C port by default - you'd have to disable that port (if that's even possible) to directly control the pin.  It would be much easier to use a pin that doesn't have any predefined function - I see GPIO 17 commonly used for LEDs.  Also, where exactly are you measuring voltage?  I'd expect to see 3.3V on GPIO 2, due to the I2C pullup resistors.  Are you aware of the different between the physical pin numbers (1-40), and the GPIO numbers (0-27, only applying to pins that actually have GPIO functionality)?

Hello Jason! Thanks for the reply. I tried using a different pin (specifically gpio pin 17). I used led.on() and led.off() and my multimeter measured the same 0.03 voltage from both. Do you know if there is anything else that might have gone wrong?
Thank you very much,
Matthew.

(for Raspberry questions you should consider https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)

Yes, thank you for the suggestion Paolo, I will post it on the rpi stack exchange.

@jasonharper I will add that when I try to turn the LED on in the gpiod library, it works.

@jasonharper Here is the code:
import gpiod
LED_PIN = 17
chip = gpiod.Chip('gpiochip4')
led_line = chip.get_line(LED_PIN)
led_line.request(consumer="LED", type=gpiod.LINE_REQ_DIR_OUT)
led_line.set_value(1)

The reason why I don't want to use the gpiod library in the long term is that I'm pretty sure it doesn't support internal pull up resistors or pwm.

I've updated the original post.
